# Spring component scan custom filter

Tags: spring

I got package structure like:

```
(...)
com.domain.group.dao
com.domain.group.service
(...)
com.domain.users.dao
com.domain.users.service
```

Is there any way to tell the spring that should scan just all the classes which package ends with "dao" or "service" ?

[here's example of similar problem](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-filtering-components-in-auto-scanning/), but it doesn't resolve my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.domain">
     <context:include-filter type="regex" expression=".*dao\.[^.]*"/>
     <context:include-filter type="regex" expression=".*service\.[^.]*"/>
 </context:component-scan>
```

@See [Spring Reference Chapter 4.10.3 Using filters to customize scanning](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-scanning-filters)

---

*Appendix:* (*because of the comments*)

*It is possible to have multiple `include-filter`s and `exclude-filter`s but the order is important: first `include-filter` then `exclude-filter`- see [`spring-context-3.0.xsd`](http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd):*

```
<xsd:element name="component-scan">
    ...
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="include-filter" type="filterType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                ...
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="exclude-filter" type="filterType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                ...
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
        ...
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Comment: You can not provide several filters under one comp-scan.

Comment: @IvanNik, your statement is incorrect. Per Springs docks: "Add them as include-filter or exclude-filter sub-elements of the component-scan element. Each filter element requires the type and expression attributes."[Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-scanning-filters)

That specifically specifies plural usage of filters.

Comment: @trash80: thanks for the answer to IvanNik - It seams I overlooked his comment -- I have updated my answer to address this fact

Answer (score 1):

```
  <context:component-scan base-package="org.example">
     <context:include-filter type="regex" expression="YOUR REGEX"/>
  </context:component-scan>
```

PS: you can have multiple include-filters one for service regex and one for dao

This is taken from the [Using filters to customize scanning section of the Spring reference guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s12.html).